# How to send data from React to Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to create login/registration for an app using React/Node/Express/Postgres. Where I'm getting stuck is receiving data on the server side from my form in React.

I have a register component for the form in `register.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import useForm from '../form/useForm';

const Register = () => {

    const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm({
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: "",
            password2: ""
        }, register);

    function register() {
        console.log(values);
    }

  return (
            <div className="row mt-5">
              <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
                <div className="card card-body">
                  <h1 className="text-center mb-3">
                    <i className="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Register
                  </h1>
                  <form 
                    action="/users/register" 
                    method="POST"
                    onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                      <input 
                      className="form-control" 
                      type="name" 
                      name="name" 
                      onChange={handleChange} 
                      placeholder="Enter Name"
                      value={values.name} 
                      required />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                      <input 
                      className="form-control" 
                      type="email" 
                      name="email" 
                      onChange={handleChange} 
                      placeholder="Enter Email"
                      value={values.email} 
                      required />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="email">Password</label>
                      <input 
                      className="form-control" 
                      type="password" 
                      name="password" 
                      onChange={handleChange} 
                      placeholder="Create Password"
                      value={values.password} 
                      required />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="email">Confirm Password</label>
                      <input 
                      className="form-control" 
                      type="password" 
                      name="password2" 
                      onChange={handleChange} 
                      placeholder="Confirm Password"
                      value={values.password2} 
                      required />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                      Register
                    </button>
                  </form>
                  <p className="lead mt-4">Have An Account? <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

A hook to handle the form actions in `useForm.js`

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const useForm = (initialValues, callback) => {

const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(setValues(values => ({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })))
    }
    fetch("/users/register", options)
  }

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    setValues(values => ({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
  };

  return {
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    values,
  }
};

export default useForm;
```

Then I have a file to manage the routes for logging in/registering in `users.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const Router = require("express-promise-router");
const db = require("../db");
const router = new Router();

//Login page
router.get('/login', (req, res) => res.send("Login"));

//Register page
router.get('/register', (req, res) => res.send("Register"));

//Register Handle
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('hecks');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have tried messing with things inside of the `handleSubmit` function in my `useForm.js` hook, but everything leads to the `console.log(req.body)` from my `users.js` file to return as `undefined`. Where am I going wrong?

**Edit #1:** Snip from Postman sending post request
[image]

**Edit #2:** basic project structure

```
.
./client
./client/src
./client/src/components
./client/src/components/register
./client/src/components/register/register.js
./client/src/components/form
./client/src/components/form/useForm.js
./client/src/App.js
./routes
./routes/index.js
./routes/users.js
./server.js
```

**Edit #3:** Main `server.js` file

```
const express = require("express");
const mountRoutes = require("./routes");
const app = express();
mountRoutes(app);
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//catch all other routes
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    res.send("<h1>Page does not exist, sorry</h1>");
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the postman showing the body?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I added a screenshot from Postman in the main post, the body is showing "hecks" which is sent from `users.js`

Comment: You need to send the request body in postman like this, first choose Body tab, then choose raw option, and then JSON in the right drop down like this:  `https://imgur.com/3fFfGn9` And for the react side, can you check my answer?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I made the React changes you suggested and re-tested in Postman with the method you provided and still seeing "undefined" in the console. I made a second edit to the main post to show my project structure. Could something be wrong there with the different files and their locations?

Comment: Can you add your server.js file to the question?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I added it as edit #3

Comment: I updated answer, now can you test first with postman?

Comment: @SuleymanSah That worked! Thank you so much for helping me out. One question, just so I have a better understanding, where should I see the logging from the `handleSubmit` function? I.e. "response ok" or "not ok".

Comment: If you are asking how to read response from your api, it is  inside the responseData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply bodyParser before mounting routes.
So change like this:

```js
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mountRoutes(app);
```

You don't use then or await in the handleSubmit function which may cause problem.

Can you update the handleSubmit function like this and try?

```js
  const handleSubmit = async event => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(values)
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch("/users/register", options);

      const responseData = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("response ok");
        callback();
      } else {
        console.log("response NOT ok");
        throw new Error(responseData.message);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      if (err.response) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You’re setting state in JSON.stringify which returns undefined. you’ve to pass values in it:

```
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(values)
    }
    fetch("/users/register", options)
  }
```

Comment: I am still receiving undefined in the console after this change. Since the `JSON.stringify(values)` is being posted in the body, then is should show up on the server in the `req.body`, right?

Answer (score 0):

‍ You can try with this code below:

**userForm.js:** Make sure your `handleSubmit` in your `userForm.js` it's looks like this code below:

```js
const handleSubmit = async(event) => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(values)
    }

    try {
        // change with your endpoint
        const endpoint = 'http://localhost:3001/users/register';
        const result = await fetch(endpoint, options);
        // send value to your register function
        callback(result);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log('Something failed');
        console.log(ex);
    }
}
```

> You've to use `callback(result)`, so you can `console.log` that value on your `register` function.

**express server:** Make sure in your express server, you've been add `body-parser`, it's will looks like this code below:

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

> That code above will make your `req.body` works.

I hope it can help you .

Comment: I made those changes but I’m still seeing undefined in the console

Comment: I've been try your code above and it's working fine. That's why I give you the code. **What the port of your server?** Have you add `body-parser` in there?

Comment: Make sure, your endpoint it's working. Please try to call your endpoint: `http://localhost:3000/users/register` from postman with `post` method and try to add some data. It's work or not.

Comment: the server is on port 5000. When I call the endpoint from Postman with a key/value in the body, I still get undefined on the console.